# Google reCaptcha Validation

Tags: model-view-controller, recaptcha, laravel-8

I am am working with Google reCaptcha in a `Registration` page using Laravel 8. My View (blade) page code is like below.

```
<div class="form-group mt-5">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="sitekeytext"></div>
</div>
@error('g-recaptcha-response')
  <div class="alert alert-danger mt-1 mb-1">{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

My Controller code is like below,

```
$request->validate([
  'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required',
],
[
   'g-recaptcha-response.required' => 'Captcha is Required',       
]);
```

After submitting `Form` I am getting `Captcha is Required` validation message.

[image]

Same code is working perfectly on `Login` page.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/anam-hossain/captcha , yes it hasn't been updated in a while but it has never let me down. At first sight I see nothing wrong with your code. Albeit, not all code is given that could indicate a logical error somewhere in your controller.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey Thanks for your reply. Actually I am not using any package. Same code is working in `Login` page but not working in `Registration` page. Do you need to see any code ?Thanks.

Comment: A bit more of the controller code would be nice. Do you see any difference between your reg page and this version? You need js from Google right. Is it possible one is a modal and the other is not. If in a modal, move the js script request on top of the modal code and delete the 'deferred' option.

Comment: Thanks @DimitriMostrey. You can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842152/google-recaptcha-is-absent-in-request-variable